# clear a view and redraw a image

Tags: iphone

How to dealloc a view and realloc it?

Code:

```
-(IBAction)CancelButton{

    [drawImage removeFromSuperview];
    [drawImage dealloc];
```

When you click on the cancel button the view gets cleared but nothing can be drawn on the page. I need to draw on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `dealloc` outside of `dealloc` and then `[super dealloc]` is the only accepted call.

```
[drawImage release];
drawImage = nil;
```

is what you should do, but if you want to reuse it the next second maybe you just want to remove it from the super view and then add it as subview or possibly just hide it:

```
drawImage.hidden = YES;
```

You should now how to allocate and initialize a view. Otherwise you should read an Objective-C tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have to release an object inorder to destroy it as follows:

```
  [drawImage release];
```

But if you want to reuse the object, then the best way to do it is to first remove it from superview as

```
  [drawImage removeFromSuperview];
```

Then you can reuse it by adding it as the subview to the current class as follows:

```
  [self addSubview:drawImage];
```